# Find the number of occurrences of the substring between string

Tags: string, python-3.x

The string is:

```
"ATGGAACTGGAAAACATGTAGTGAGATCTGATGGAAAACAATCTG".
```

The substring must be between `"ATG"` and `"CTG"`, I need to find the number of times the substring occurs in the string given above. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this with a regular expression pretty easily.

Comment: `s='ATGGAACTGGAAAACATGTAGTGAGATCTGATGGAAAACAATCTG'; print(s[3:-3].count(substring_goes_here))`

Comment: okay, what if I cant know the sub string, I just know where the string starts and where it is supposed to end. I will need to do use this program for a much larger example